# Same shape/size of training set and validation set with history.history() function

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm, prediction

I am referring to the [code for Regression analysis](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tjIOud2Cc6smmvZsbl-QDBA6TLA2iEtd#scrollTo=yWuxznPhATyL). The validation_split is set at `0.05`:

```py
# fit the network
history = model.fit(seq_array, label_array, epochs=100, batch_size=200, validation_split=0.05, verbose=2,
          callbacks = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=10, verbose=0, mode='min'),
                       keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(model_path,monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True, mode='min', verbose=0)]
          )

# list all data in history
print(history.history.keys())
```

Then I plot the R2 value:

```py
# summarize history for R^2
fig_acc = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.plot(history.history['r2_keras'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_r2_keras'])
plt.title('model r^2')
plt.ylabel('R^2')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
fig_acc.savefig("model_r2.png")
```

[image: r2 graph]

My question is: why `history.history['r2_keras']` and `history.history['val_r2_keras']` have the same number of elements when validation_split is set at `0.05`.